# Problemas con zsh en windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, consola, zsh

Estoy usando zsh y oh-my-zsh en Windows 10. Seguí todos los pasos de este [blog](https://platzi.com/blog/como-instalar-zsh-en-windows/). Todo me salió bien, pero ahora que intento utilizar comandos como node --version o comandos de npm no me los reconoce, me manda esto: zsh: command not found: node
¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Bienvenido Christiam a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Añade la ruta de instalación a tu variable PATH. Hay preguntas y respuestas sobre eso en este foro. Te sugiero que las busques